# How to handle many light sources on the scene?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I have a map definition with plenty of light sources (about 350). When I'm trying to create THREE.PointLight objects and add them to the scene, I'm getting the following error along with low FPS:

```
three.js:29438 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog Fragment shader active uniforms exceed MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS (1024).
```

What does it mean? Is there some limit of THREE.PointLight objects on the scene? Are there any good practices to keep high performance when you have many light sources?

For now the only idea that comes to mind is somehow reduce the number of light sources and leaving only those that I really need.

Comment: For every light you are adding, three.js needs to add some uniforms into the shader (position, strength etc.).  MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS depends on the graphic card. So how many lights you really could handle depends on your device.

Comment: Three.js uses "forward rendering" by default. Forward rendering usually has a limit of a few lights. To get around that requires turning lights on and off (or removing them from the scene) so there are only ever a few actually used at any one time.  "deferred rendering" removes those limits (as a trade off it has some other limit).  There have been a few deferred renderers implemented for three.js. You might want to Google that.

Comment: Last I checked the deferredWebGLRenderer was removed from Three.js due to maintenance overhead. Some of the features will be implemented after WebGL 2.0 release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means you've exceeded the maximum number of uniforms in your fragment shader. This limit is determined by your graphics card and/or driver. You can check by going to http://webglreport.com/.

Looks like on your system the limit is 1024. A Three.js light typically uses 6-10 uniforms depending on the type of light and the material. Given you're using ~350 lights, it makes sense that you're blowing way past this limit.

Generally speaking, 350 discrete lights is **a lot**, probably way more than you need. Using more lights is also computationally intensive. A typical WebGL scene has no more than a handful. You might want to consider other techniques to achieve what you want.

Comment: Where can I find the exact number of uniforms used by three.js light types ?